# win universal linq from url

Tags: c#, linq

i use linq to parse xml from url :

```
class emp_com
{
public object details_emp(string xml_file)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml_file);
        var detail = from query in xdoc.Descendants("emp")
                        select new class_emp.emp_detail
                        {
                            Name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                            Age = (string)query.Element("age"),
                        };
        return detail;
    }
  }
```

this is code in page:

```
        url = "https://aaa.bbb.ccc.file_xml.xml";
        emp_com ec = new emp_com();
        object obj = ec.details_emp(url.ToString());
        listbox_detail.ItemsSource = obj;
```

with this code, in win i can parse xml.
but with this code, in winphone i get error ( can't parse xml ).
how to fix it?

Comment: what error u are getting?

Comment: @Webruster : error in XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml_file);

Comment: please post the application error !!

Comment: @Webruster : An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in SYSTEM.XML.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot open 'https:/aaa.bbb.ccc.file_xml.xml'. The Uri parameter must be a file system relative path.

Comment: Seems like the file can't be found...

Comment: @code4life : i don't think so. because in win i can parse it, but in winphone i can't(same code).

Comment: @1234abcd i am assuming that string xml_file path is not correct check that , in windows phone it will be accessed based on http , but in the win form it can accessed through the directory path also

Comment: @Webruster: me too. but with same code, it working in win, but can't work in winphone.

Comment: The error is quite clear. It takes one more line of code to do a sanity check, right? Also not a very good assumption, that win and win phone are identical, out even orthogonal.

Comment: @codelife: can you fix it?

Comment: @1234abcd `https://aaa.bbb.ccc.file_xml.xml`  did u pasted this link in the Browser?

Comment: @Webruster: yes, and with my code, it work on win, but not working in winphone(win universal app).